# cordova build android in windows 10 shows the following issue

Tags: java, android, windows, cordova

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\MI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)

ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)

Using Android SDK: C:\Users\MI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: null

Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.

Comment: Then maybe just install Java JDK 1.8

Comment: The title of question is very important it must include the programming problem so it is searchable.

Answer (score 0):

You can open "*.../platforms/android*" using Android Studio and build the APK from there.
I use your command just to build Javascript files, then I switch to Android Studio to launch Debugging or to produce final APK.